# Kotlin implicit override using delegation

Tags: kotlin

I have the following base class and interface

```
open class Base {
    open fun foo() { println("Base.foo") }
}

fun interface Delegate {
    fun foo(): Unit
}
```

Now I want to override the `foo` method of a subclass `Composed` of `Base` using delegation, like this:

```
class Composed(delegate: Delegate) : Base(), Delegate by delegate
```

This works as I intend. Instances of `Composed` use the `foo` method of `delegate`, instead of the one from `Base`. **But**, I get a warning from IntelliJ:

> Delegated member 'fun foo(): Unit' hides supertype override: public open fun foo(): Unit defined in Base. Please specify proper override explicitly.

Why do I get this error? What is "bad" about implicitly overriding the `foo` method? Are there any drawbacks I don't see? Specifying the override explicitly seems like a lot of unnecessary code, especially if I do this for multiple methods and multiple subclasses.

Comment: Can you post the source code for Foo too?

Comment: @PaulNUK oops that's a mistake. Should be Delegate instead of Foo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there's a warning for at least two reasons:

1. The behavior is ambiguous about which `foo()` implementation is used. There's no intuitive expectation about which `foo()` should win, since the superclass and the delegate are declared on the same line. I've been using Kotlin for a few years, and I couldn't have told you which behavior to expect without testing it, because this is kind of an unusual setup.
2. You will get possibly unexpected behavior if any of the functions in the Base superclass call `foo()`, because they will be calling the delegate's `foo()` instead of their own. It might be OK in this case, but in most cases, when you override a function, you want to call super in case there are necessary side-effects. That's not possible with the delegate.

Comment: Reading those 2 reasons alone, I wish it were a compile error and not just a warning

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Seems like this is not a very good idea to do

Comment: I don't see why there should be an issue. Kotlin documentation says "if a class inherits multiple implementations of the same member from its immediate superclasses, it must override this member and provide its own implementation " https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inheritance.html#overriding-rules. So the the two inherited functions will be overridden as one.
When this is clear, then result of overriding by the delegation is clear.

Comment: P.S. if I correctly understand "hides supertype override", then it means it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When you have functions with the same from several interfaces, you should specify implementation for every interface like this:

```
override fun foo(){
super<Base>.foo()
super<Delegate>.foo()
}
```